# updating drive mapping GPO programmatically using powershell

Tags: group-policy, powershell

I have a Group Policy in a domain that have lots of drive mapping settings.
I would like to change the path for a lot of these servers in this gpo with powershell if possible. I know i could do this via the GPMC, but would prefer to do it programtically.
I have looked at the grouppolicy powershell module from microsoft (get-gpo and friends) but i only seem to be able to change registry entrys and permissions on the policys, not the actual path for the drivemapping. any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: How are you mapping drives? Logon script or Group Policy Preference?

Answer (score -1):

To change GPOs you've got to use the Set-GPPrefRegistryValue for preferences or Set-GPRegistryValue for other values.  All a GPO does is set registry values so the paths are actually just registry values.

Comment: Those cmdlet's only change registry-based settings. GPP drive mappings are stored in an XML file (`Drives.xml`).